# RadioButton not visible on Android 10/11 with light theme

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, radio-button

We are using the new experimental radio button in Xamarin Forms:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton

Xamarin.Forms version - 4.8.0.1269

The radio buttons work perfectly in Android 9 and lower devices.
But on Android 10/11, if the phone theme is set to Light theme, the Radio button icon goes missing.
Here are the sample screenshots from both dark and light themes respectively:

[image: Dark theme on emulator]

[image: Light theme on Samsung device]

And here is the code written for the radio buttons:

```
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                        <Label Text="Body temperature"
                               Style="{StaticResource BlackBoldLabelStyle}"
                               VerticalOptions="Start"
                               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />

                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                     Margin="0,10,0,0"
                                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnBodyTempOption1Click}"/>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                            <RadioButton
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                   IsChecked="{Binding IsBodyTempOption1Check}"/>

                            <Label Text="Less than 99.5 degree F / 37.5 degree C"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   Style="{StaticResource DarkGrayLabelStyle}"
                                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                        </StackLayout>

                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                     Margin="0,5,0,0"
                                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnBodyTempOption2Click}"/>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                            <RadioButton
                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center" 
                                IsChecked="{Binding IsBodyTempOption2Check}"/>

                            <Label Text="More than 99 degree F / 37 degree C"
                               VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   Style="{StaticResource DarkGrayLabelStyle}"
                               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
```

Please help on how to fix the issue with the radio button visibility.

Comment: I did not reproduce the problem on my side while I get an other problem. Does it work in a lower Xamarin.forms version? RadioButton is currently experimental and you can report this problem in Github.

Comment: OK, once you find a solution, you can also share here.

Comment: There are currently known issues with Radio Button & Android platform with the release of Xamarin Forms 4.8.  https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11700     https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/184021/text-of-radio-buttons-not-showing-anymore.   How could they screw this up!

Comment: Could you give a feedback if this issue is still reproducible or no?

Comment: @Cfun It was due to the light/dark theme.

Comment: I am using Xamarin.Forms version 5.0.0.2012. In that, RadioButton control is removed from experimental phase. When I run my app(Android 11) in dark theme mode, entry control text and radiobutton(non-selected) is not visible (shown in white color). When I switched to light theme mode during app is in running state, same issue arises. Once I closed and re-opened the app, entry text and radiobutton shows perfectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Xamarin.Fomrs dev team working on [this issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10320) you can apply the following workaround, in Android `styles.xml` set the following attribute:

```
<item name="android:colorControlNormal">#FF4081</item>
```

which will set a color to the `RadioButton` circle.

Comment: For Xamarin.Forms version 5.0.0.2012, this issue exists.

Comment: this workaround adds the tint color to all editable controls.