# Xamarin.Forms RadioButtons Text Not Visible

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, radio-button

I'm using the experimental radio buttons in `Xamarin.Forms`, everything was working fine but suddenly the radio buttons text stopped appearing.

```
public RequestsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Device.SetFlags(new string[] { "RadioButton_Experimental" }); // to be able to use radio buttons        
    }
```

Comment: SetFlags should be called in the platform project init or in the Forms App class, not in an individual page - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/experimental-flags

Comment: but it was working fine previously. Today I reopened the app and the texts were invisible

Comment: What is your Xamarin.Forms package version? Try to update to the latest, because there was a bug in a previous version. Also clean the solution and rebuild after the update.

Comment: Yeah I remembered, when I updated to the latest version this happened! They have to fix this. I don't know what version I had before updating

Comment: 4.8.0.1560 it was released a while ago, I updated to this version and the problem appeared

Comment: can u give me more details please?

Answer (score 6):

There was a bug introduced in version 4.8.0 causing the `RadioButton` text not to show, fortounately this was fixed starting from version 5.0.0 pre-1 and higher.

In your Nuget Package manager check the "include pre realeases" option and select 5.0.0 pre-1 or the latest. You can also roll back by selecting a previous working version before the bug was introduced if you prefere.

If you choosed to update you may need to change your target platform version.

If you encounter some compilation errors then change your `RadioButton` syntax from:

```
<RadioButton Text="click"/>
```

To

```
<RadioButton Content="click"/>
```

If you want to stick with your current xf version, then take a look at this [sugessted workaround](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11700#issuecomment-681160682)

**EDIT**

Starting from Xamarin.Forms version **5.0.0.1539-pre2** experimental flag for `RadioButton` has been dropped (no longer needed) and is considered stable by the dev team.

Comment: I tried your solution but it required me to change the target framework which I don't prefer to do

Comment: Yea I forgot to mention that.

Comment: This is really annoying, now I have to change many xaml files

Comment: @Sam in this case I am afraid the simplest solution would be to roll back to a version before 4.8.0.

Comment: There's a workaround where I add label beside the radio button.. I think I'll go with that

Comment: It is more visually annoying in code but it's your choice

Comment: For solution, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63712512/radiobutton-not-visible-on-android-10-11-with-light-theme)